# How to multiply string?

Tags: python

I have a number that is represented as a string. I need to multiply this number by -1.

```
        myvalue = htmlcontent.find_next(class_='floatRight').text
        print(myvalue)
        myvalue = myvalue * -1
        print(myvalue)
```

The above outputs the following:

> -0.1234

The second print doesn't display anything. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Cast the string to a float

Comment: Multiplying a string won't multiply by value, but the actual string. `"moo" * 2` will become `moomoo`. Hence, doing a negative multiplication will subtract all of the string. Much like doing `"moo" * 0` will produce a zero length string. if you're from a JavaScript background, this might be confusing because of automated lazy operations. But here, you will at least need to re-cast the variable type when doing such operations.

Comment: Just use the debugger and see what's the content first! :/

Comment: `int(myvalue)*-1`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Short answer: `float(myvalue) * -1`.

You're trying to multiply a string with some number. Multiplying a string (say `s`) with a number (say `n`) will concatenate the same string `n` times. And if `n` is less than or equal to 0, then it'll return an empty string.

You're multiplying your string by `-1`, that's why you're getting an empty string. If you multiply it with `2`, you'll get `-0.1234-0.1234`.